# with powershell want to run batch file from multiple batches according the user selected

Tags: powershell

I want to run batch files on user selection from multiple  number of batches present in folder.

Currently i am using this code but after selecting option as 1 or 2 or other option batch file is not running on location where it is currently present.

My Code :

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\11558851\Desktop\244BP\Fast run Batch 87" -File
$fileChoices = @()

for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
  $fileChoices += [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]("$($files[$i].Name) &$($i+1)")
}

$userChoice = $host.UI.PromptForChoice('Select File', 'Choose a file', $fileChoices, 0) + 1

# do something more useful here...
Write-Host "you chose $($files[$userChoice].FullName)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Array indices count from zero, not one. Also it is slow to add items to an array using `+=`.

Try

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\11558851\Desktop\244BP\Fast run Batch 87" -File -Filter '*.bat'

$fileChoices = for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
    [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]("$($files[$i].Name) (&$($i+1))")
}

$userChoice = $host.UI.PromptForChoice('Select File', 'Choose a file', $fileChoices, 0)

# do something more useful here...
Write-Host "you chose $($files[$userChoice].FullName)"
```

Result:

[image]

After clicking a button or pressing the corresponding number between brackets on the keyboard you will get the correct path:

```
you chose C:\Users\11558851\Desktop\244BP\Fast run Batch 87\Blah 3.bat
```